# Можно ли авторизироваться в API яндекса без подтверждения пользователя?

Tags: авторизация, oauth, яндекс-id

Есть ли возможность авторизироваться в API яндекса без подтверждения пользователя. А точнее, чтобы скрипт мог автоматически получать токен без участия пользователя?

Comment: нет, нельзя